# Degree Symbol missing in PolarPlot when exported to PDF

Tags: plotting, export, pdf-format

I am trying to produce a polar plot. The axis should be in degrees. While no error occurs, the `pdf` export isn't working properly. Instead of the degree symbol I get a square (while using `acrobat`) and a 'D' when I use `nitro`. The code I am using is

```
r = 2.81794*10^(-15);
m = 511;
a1 = 1/m;
a2 = 5.9/m;
ds1[theta_] := 
 10*r^2*(1/(1 + a1*(1 - Cos[theta])))*((1 + Cos[theta]*Cos[theta])/
  2)*(1 + (a1^2*(1 - Cos[theta])^2)/((1 + 
     Cos[theta]*Cos[theta])*(1 + a1*(1 - Cos[theta]))))
ds2[theta_] := 
 10*r^2*(1/(1 + a2*(1 - Cos[theta])))*((1 + Cos[theta]*Cos[theta])/
2)*(1 + (a2^2*(1 - Cos[theta])^2)/((1 + 
     Cos[theta]*Cos[theta])*(1 + a2*(1 - Cos[theta]))))

Needs["PlotLegends`"]
PolarPlot[{ds1[theta], ds2[theta]}, {theta, -π, π}, PolarAxes -> True, 
  PolarGridLines -> True, PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, 
  PlotRange -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> 
  Style[Framed["Klein-Nishina Compton Cross Section"], 20, Red, 
   Background -> Lighter[Yellow]], 
   PlotLegend -> {"1keV", "5.9keV"}, LegendShadow -> {.01, -.01}, LegendTextSpace -> 5, 
  LegendBackground -> LightPurple, LegendSize -> {0.5, 0.5}, 
   Background -> LightYellow] 

 Export["Klein.pdf", %]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I also tried to export it in other formats, which is working fine, however I need `.pdf` format...

Comment: Please try to post a **Minimal** working example that displays the behavior you want to show.

Comment: You are propably true; that wasn't a minimum...I'll edit the question!

Comment: @Thanos I get a degree symbol correctly when I export to PDF (Mac OSX 10.8, MMA 8.0.4). It could be because some fonts are missing on your system...

Comment: @Thanos I also get a degree symbol when I export to PDF (Win 7 MMA 8.0.4).

Comment: I see...It is most certainly my particular system...Do you have any idea whatsoever, which fonts should be installed to view the degree symbol?

Comment: You should be able to set the fonts in your graph to a standard font.  My guess is you don't have Mathematica fonts installed.

Comment: Try to add this option at the end of your `PolarPlot`: `BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}` or any other font that is installed on your computer.

Comment: Try evaluating `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, PrivateFontOptions -> {"OperatorSubstitution" -> False}]` before your code to produce the plot.

Comment: The displayed code is missing something near its end, before `Export` -- perhaps additional options, certainly a closing `'`. Also, the code does not produce the displayed plot but instead calculates, displays, and labels only the 1keV and 59keV curves.

Comment: I tried to change `font style` using VLC's code `BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}`. The font is indeed `Helvetica` but again no degree symbol. I tried with other fonts but again nothing happens... I also tried `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, PrivateFontOptions -> {"OperatorSubstitution" -> False}]` before plotting but again this doesn't solve the issue...

Comment: @murray: You are right...I forgot to close `PolarPlot` with `]`...Now it's OK! Thank you very much for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Force use of system fonts by the following:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 PrivateFontOptions -> {"OperatorSubstitution" -> False}]
```

or

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, 
 PrivateFontOptions -> {"OperatorSubstitution" -> False}]
```

Note: Options set for `$FrontEnd` are by default stored in the front end init.m file, and are persistent between front end sessions. (ref. [$FrontEnd](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24FrontEnd.html))

Failing that try another PDF creator.

Comment: I tried both ways but unfortunately it didn't work... I tried again with `nitro reader` and `adobe acrobat reader` nut the issue remains... I also tried with `Ocular` and `Ubuntu's Document Viewer` but again no degree symbol...

Comment: What OS and version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: I am running `Mathematica 8.0.0` in `Windows Vista`.

Comment: I also tried in `FoxIt` but again nothing happened...

Comment: How about CutePDF. Install, then File -> Print, select Printer Name: CutePDF Writer.  Very reliable. http://www.cutepdf.com/products/cutepdf/writer.asp