# Text symbols not exporting correctly to PDF [version 13.2]

Tags: plotting, export, labeling, text, pdf-format

I am using Mathematica 13.2 on Ubuntu. I was trying to reproduce a plot that I made using Mathematica 12, but text symbols seem to not export correctly to PDF. This issue seems to apply to all non-letter/numerical symbols (e.g. parentheses, pound-signs, etc.)

I have boiled my problem down to a minimal-ish working example. Consider this simple plot of $\sin (x)$.

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -3, 3}
  , ImageSize -> Large
  , TicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 25]
  , LabelStyle -> {Directive[FontSize -> 40, FontColor -> Black], 
    Directive[FontSize -> 40]}
  , AxesLabel -> {"x", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Psi]\), \(\[Pi]\)]\)(x)"}
  , PlotRangePadding -> {0.2, 0.2}
  , PlotStyle -> {{Red, AbsoluteThickness[t1*1.5]}}
  , PlotLegends -> 
   LineLegend[{Directive[Red, AbsoluteThickness[t2]]}, 
    Style[#, 35, 
       FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"] & /@ {"Test (blep)"}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> l]
  ] /. {t1 -> 3, t2 -> 6, l -> 40}
```

The plot that is generated in the Mathematica notebook is perfectly correct.

[image]

I then export this plot to PDF using the following command:

```
Export["/home/myComputer/test.pdf", %, "PDF"]
```

The plot in the generated PDF file does not have correct axes & legend labels. All symbols appear to be screwed up.

[image]

**Any idea how to correct this?**

---

### Edit:

I have noticed that the error does not exist with other non-vector graphic types. For example, if I export to jpeg, gif, or png, the symbols show up correctly.

Comment: There were some problems reported here before with pdf exporting on Linux with some fonts not showing correctly. Your example works fine on windows 10. Linux always had problem with fonts.

Comment: @Nasser Oh wow that's interesting. I have actually tried changing to various different fonts in my plot and the problem persists. It seems to not be related to the specific font on my computer.

Comment: Well, if you google linux font problem you'll see. Here is one [example](https://pandasauce.org/post/linux-fonts/). Linux after 30 years still can't figure how to handle fonts right, for some reason. I do not think it is Mathematica's problem, but ofcourse I can't be sure. btw, I use Linux more than windows myself, but I only use the terminal/bash (via Vbox) and all my main GUI apps I use are on windows.

Comment: Maybe try PrivateFontOptions e.g. [SE post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10810/363)

Comment: @Nasser I never had this issue with previous versions of Mathematica though. I have only ever used Mathematica on my current computer, which has always ran on Ubuntu.

Comment: I have the same problem occasionally, usually solved by restarting the kernel.  Out of nothing Mathematica randomly decides to replace minus signs with different characters.  Started getting it a few years back (so perhaps around v.12).  Here's a minimal non-working example (Export command and its output opened in zathura) https://imgur.com/a/gFmhekt.  I don't think it has anything to do with Linux, here it clearly is Mathematica's inability to produce a meaningful PDF even with default fonts.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is any help:
I just had a knock-down-drag-out-fight with Mathematica on this kind of problem in Fedora 37.
Every time I saved a notebook as PDF or used the Print preview feature, half the text would come out garbled.
I went through some of my old notes, and discovered that when I had this problem before, I was able to solve it by uninstalling the Adobe SourceCode fonts.
Mathematica has its own version of those fonts that is somehow different from whatever the Fedora folks package up.
Your problem seems to be related to the Latin Modern fonts which I believe are part of TeX.
I suspect that TeX fonts are encoded some way that Mathematica is not expecting, so maybe try changing the font on your plot to something like Times New Roman?

Comment: Thanks Garrett, I have tried a zillion different fonts (including Times New Roman) and the problem persists.

Comment: Hmm. I experimented with your example just now on Fedora 37, Mathematica 13.1, and the exported file was produced correctly, no garbled symbols. I tried it with both the "default" and "journal article" style sheets and both worked. I've uninstalled the Adobe Source Code fonts, which were definitely resulting in garbled exported PDFs, and then restarted Mathematica.

Comment: How did you uninstall this? (I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and never actively installed such a thing but perhaps it came with it? I have no idea how I would find it and uninstall it.)

Comment: On Fedora, there's an RPM package for the Adobe SourceCode fonts, and you use dnf or Gnome Software to remove it.I haven't found an Ubuntu package for them. It seems that you have to install them manually on Ubuntu. If you didn't do that, they may not even be installed on your machine, which would indicate that your problem has a different source than mine. Look in ~/.fonts/ and /usr/share/fonts and see if there are files named something like SourceCodePro-xxx.otf. You can try moving them out of the way, and see if Mathematica produces correct exported graphics.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by installing the font Source Code Pro.
I make the download by https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Source+Code+Pro
and use the font-manager for installation.